# Link to footnote export as non-superscript

Tags: org-mode, latex, org-link

Links to a footnote automatically exports as superscript in LaTeX.

## Source:

```org
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. [fn:1685d75dd9ccdec5: This is a footnote.] In sed erat porta, sodales mauris congue, volutpat nisi. Integer in justo ac augue vehicula sodales ac quis enim. [fn:4194cf1977de9b2:Please refer to footnote [fn:1685d75dd9ccdec5].]
```

## TeX:

```latex
Please refer to footnote \textsuperscript{\ref{orge6f2964}}.
```

Is there a setting that can turn off this feature so that this specific link is exported normally?

```latex
Please refer to footnote \text{\ref{orge6f2964}}.
```

---

## Expected Results:

I would like links in the main text to remain super-scripted.
[image]

While those within footnotes to be in normal text.
[image]
i.e. Please refer to footnote 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine `org-latex-footnote-defined-format`. Its doc string
says:

> org-latex-footnote-defined-format is a variable defined in ‘ox-latex.el’.
> Its value is "\textsuperscript{\ref{%s}}"
>
> You can customize this variable.
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
> version 26.1 of Emacs.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Format string used to format reference to footnote already defined.
> %s will be replaced by the label of the referred footnote.

You can redefine it in your init file with

```el
(eval-after-load 'ox-latex
   (setq org-latex-footnote-defined-format "\\text{\\ref{%s}}"))
```

or if you prefer using a [file local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html#File-Variables) by adding something like this at the end of your file:

```
* Local customizations                        :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# org-latex-footnote-defined-format: "\\text{\\ref{%s}}"
# End:
```

Comment: I don't know of any way to differentiate footnote links within a footnote from other footnote links in Org mode itself. There's probably ways to do it in LaTeX, that can be used in your Org mode file (at the price of making it exportable correctly only to LaTeX, but I gather that does not matter to you.)

Comment: How about using inline latex code to counteract the superscript in such cases? Would that be feasible?

Comment: Yes, I think so - as I just amended my earlier comment to say ;-) Real time communication over comments is ... difficult :-)

Comment: Edited to clarify the applicability of the answer.

Comment: I think you are right... The variable *does* make the change I want without affecting the superscript footnote link in the main text. Except that the required string is `"\text{\ref{%s}}"` rather than `"\\text{\\ref{%s}}"`.

Comment: Even more simple would be `"\ref{%s}"`.